# Equivalent to Python's Zip in List-comprehension for Mathematica?

Tags: python, functional-programming, zip, wolfram-mathematica, list-comprehension

People in Mathematica.SE apparently have a Python-phobia [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60414/mathematicas-equivalent-to-the-pythons-zip-command-in-list-comprehension) so I ask this here: what is equivalent to Python's ZIP in list-comprehension for Mathematica?

**Python**

```
>>> [(ii,jj) for (ii,jj) in zip((1,10,100),(2,20,200))]
[(1, 2), (10, 20), (100, 200)]
>>> [(ii,jj,kk) for (ii,jj,kk) in zip((1,10,100),(2,20,200),(3,30,300))]
[(1, 2, 3), (10, 20, 30), (100, 200, 300)]
```

**Mathematica?**

1. `Thread[Times[{1, 11}, {2, 22}]]` is a bit similar but not equivalent (fail?)
2. other methods?

Comment: the question appears to be answered.  All you can say is your example is too simple to reveal the problem, then  come up with a better example.

Comment: @george You are right in that, general question would be to find the analogous programming style between Mathematica and Python for list-comprehensions -- I have to think how to approach that puzzle. I don't know yet, perhaps it is Map. I love list-comprehensions in Python, I can do anything with them -- trying to dig this opportunity in Mathematica :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only looking to re-arrange the elements as specified in your example then @Alan has the correct answer. In the more general sense, Pythons list comprehensions are equivalent to what other language call "map" and "filter" although in your case you don't seem to be using any filters. 
The problem can be broken down in two steps:

1. Zipping elements of some lists.
2. Creating a new list out of this new list.

So in addition to the `transpose`, you might want to use the `Map` function. Here is an example:

```
PythonZipMap[func_, list_List] := Map[func, Transpose[list]];
```

This function first performs a "zip" of your list and then applies an expression to each entry.

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {10, 20, 30}, {100, 200, 300}};
PythonZipMap[Identity, list]
{{1, 10, 100}, {2, 20, 200}, {3, 30, 300}}
PythonZipMap[Total, list]
{111, 222, 333}
PythonZipMap[Median, list]
{10, 20, 30}
```

I'm really just starting with Mathematica so I'm sure that others will have even better answers.

--- Update ---

If the resulting zipped list elements should be passed as inputs to your function you could also use  `MapThread`. For example, the above Total could have been implemented like this:

```
MapThread[Plus, list]
{111, 222, 333}
```

Comment: I find it smart to have a such programming style that both Pythonists and Mathematicanists can understand or better easy to adapt to another language, perhaps the Map is the way to go -- I don't know yet but testing, happy to see more Pythonists to use Mathematica :)

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 or Python 3?  Python 2 actually creates these objects, in which case the equivalent seems

```
Transpose@{{1, 10, 100}, {2, 20, 200}}
Transpose@{{1, 10, 100}, {2, 20, 200}, {3, 30, 300}}
```

This ignores the non-rectangular case since your example did not raise that issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
zip[{} ..] := {};
zip [p : xs__] /; MemberQ[{p}, {}] := {};
zip[p : Repeated[_List, {2, \[Infinity]}]] := Join[Through[{Apply[First[{#}]&,
{##}, {1}]&}[p]], zip[(Rest[{##1}] & @@@ {p}) /. {x__List} :> Sequence[x]]]
```

using lists of different lengths:

```
zip[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}, {10, 11, 12}]
(* {{1, 4, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 8, 11}} *)
```

using lists of same length:

```
zip[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}]
(* {{1, 4, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 8, 11}, {3, 6, 9, 12}} *)
```